# Expression is of wrong type error message while compiling trigger 

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

I am getting the below error. Don't know why this error is popping up. Please suggest:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_trigger
  2
  3    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF DRIVER_NUM
  4
  5    ON   test_driver  FOR EACH ROW
  7    DECLARE
  8
  9    Invalid_Number EXCEPTION;
 10
 11    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(Invalid_Number , -01722);
 12
 13     BEGIN
 14   
 15        IF TO_NUMBER(:NEW.DRIVER_NUM) THEN
 16   
 17            :NEW.DRIVER_NUM := TO_NUMBER(:NEW.DRIVER_NUM) ;
 18
 19        END IF;
 20
 21        EXCEPTION
 22
 23           WHEN Invalid_Number THEN
 24
 25              :NEW.DRIVER_NUM := NULL;
 26
 27      END;
/
 28
Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.
SQL> show errors
Errors for TRIGGER TEST_TRIGGER:
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
9/2      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
9/5      PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
```

Answer (score 1):

`IF TO_NUMBER(:NEW.DRIVER_NUM) THEN` is not a valid expression.

I guess you want something like:

`IF TO_NUMBER(:NEW.DRIVER_NUM) > 0 THEN`

But what's more important, your code doesn't make sense at all. I don't understand why you assign the contents of a column to the same column itself:

```
 :NEW.DRIVER_NUM := TO_NUMBER(:NEW.DRIVER_NUM);
```

If `DRIVER_NUM` is already a numeric column, that this doesn't make sense at all (converting a number to a number?).

If `DRIVER_NUM` is e.g. a `VARCHAR` then this makes even less sense

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you are trying to ensure that a VARCHAR2 column DRIVER_NUM contains only valid numbers - if not, set it to null.  If that's what you want, try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_trigger
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF DRIVER_NUM
ON   test_driver
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    Dummy NUMBER;
    Invalid_Number EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(Invalid_Number , -01722);
BEGIN
    Dummy := TO_NUMBER(:NEW.DRIVER_NUM) ;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN Invalid_Number THEN
      :NEW.DRIVER_NUM := NULL;
END;
```

Comment: Well eventhough trigger compiles but doesnt fire when the condition is met.Like -:   SQL> insert into test_driver values('ABC');
insert into test_driver values('ABC')
                               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: If the column DRIVER_NUM in the table is defined as NUMBER then this trigger approach will not work at all; my answer is based on the assumption that the column is VARCHAR2 (as I said).  It will not work on a NUMBER column because the ORA-01722 is raised before the trigger even fires.

Comment: If it had been a varchar it would

Comment: That's right, no trigger is going to do what you want.  It isn't even a good idea, in my opinion: if the user tries to enter '123' but by mistake enters '12W', instead of letting them correct their mistake you are going to store a NULL...

Comment: Yes I need that only. In oracle 10g pragma exception_init is there to catch all sql errors but not sure why its not working here.

Comment: The field which the user inserts should be a number if not it should be initialised to null and then inserted as my field is a NUMBER with NUll allowed.I was asked to write the trigger.

Comment: OK, well you need to tell your boss that it **is not going to work**!  The trigger fires **after** Oracle checks that the data is OK to be inserted, so if you try to insert a non-numeric string into a NUMBER column ORA-01722 is raised and the trigger does **not** fire.

Answer (score 0):

Try leaving out "OF DRIVER_NUM" and using it like this:

```
/* Formatted on 1/06/2011 9:10:59 (QP5 v5.114.809.3010) */
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_trigger
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON test_driver
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   INVALID_NUMBER EXCEPTION;
   PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (INVALID_NUMBER, -01722);
BEGIN
   IF TO_NUMBER (:NEW.DRIVER_NUM)
   THEN
      :NEW.DRIVER_NUM := TO_NUMBER (:NEW.DRIVER_NUM);
   END IF;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN INVALID_NUMBER
   THEN
      :NEW.DRIVER_NUM := NULL;
END;
```

If I understand what you are trying to do, you wanted to create a trigger on a certain field only? This is not necessary, or even possible for that matter afaik.

Comment: My requirement was to check if the attribute DRIVER_NUM is not a number , if so assign null to it before inserting in my trigger. The DRIVER_NUM is a NUMBER.I want to catch the sql error -01722(Invalid number) in my trigger and set it to null.